# Where is the Auth class -- Google Play Services 8.3.0

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services

I'm going through the new documentation for implementing Google Play Services 8.3.0 on Android and it seems that I need to import `com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;` but don't know which dependency to add to my build.gradle file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll want to add

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0
```

to your `build.gradle` as per the [setup guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#add_google_play_services)

Answer (score 1):

For more recent things add this to your gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
```

Comment: use: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.0'; or more recent version instead of compile